# useEffect renders more than once even with empty dependency list

Tags: reactjs

Here is my useEffect code block:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const checkNextEmailTime = async () => {
      const result = await agent.ContactCustomer.nextEmailTime();

      const now = new Date();
      const change = new Date(result);

      if(change > now) {
        setNextEmail(dateFormat(result, 'h:MM TT'));
        setEmailPendingWarning(true);
      } else {
        setNextEmail('');
        setEmailPendingWarning(false);
      }

      setTimeout(checkNextEmailTime, 60000);
    }

    checkNextEmailTime();
  }, [])
```

I would expect to see this only ping my server every 60 seconds, yet what I am seeing is it will make a request from the server, wait 60 seconds, request again, then about 10 seconds later I see another request come in. This then repeats every 60 seconds.

As far as I know, this functional component only gets loaded one time.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try to create a new function and remove `setTimeout` to the function, add `useState`

```js
const [reload,setReload] = useState(false)
```

call this function and make it change the state `setReload(!reload)` and make your useEffect dependecy is `reload`, so now every 60 seconds state shloud change and call useEffect

```js
const [reload,setReload] = useState(false)
useEffect(()=>{
checkNextEmailTime();

},[reload])

const checkNextEmailTime = ()=>{
// your code
...

setReload(!reload)
setTimeout(checkNextEmailTime, 60000);

}
```

**I hope it helps**

Comment: Thanks but when I tried implementing this, a warning popped up telling me to wrap checkNextEmailTime in useCallback, so I did. It then turned into an infinite update loop.

Answer (score 0):

Following the trail @Ahmed left for me, I did some tweaking and came to this as the solution:

```
const checkNextEmailTime = useCallback(async () => {
    const result = await agent.ContactCustomer.nextEmailTime();

    const now = new Date();
    const change = new Date(result);

    if(change > now) {
      setNextEmail(dateFormat(result, 'h:MM TT'));
      setEmailPendingWarning(true);
    } else {
      setNextEmail('');
      setEmailPendingWarning(false);
    }

    setTimeout(checkNextEmailTime, 60000);
}, []);

useEffect(() => {
    checkNextEmailTime();
}, [checkNextEmailTime])
```

I didn't need to create a reload useState variable. Thanks for the help!